# SIte for preparing Microsoft Exam?

Tags: azure

2 years ago I was studying for microsoft exams. Now I'm at it again. I remember using a site with actual exam questions.
In my memory it was something like iokings but the only thing I can find is aiotestkings.com (in which the title king refers to the prices, those are royal :|  )

Can anyone point me towards a good site for free practicing microsoft exams?
Is it actually legal to use an exam with actual exam- questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/training.aspx
and https://www.measureup.com/microsoft-technical/microsoft-practice-tests.html.

Moreover, you can learn from microsoft docs for individual topic. It is good source to get authentic technical content.

Comment: I saw thos, I forgot to mention that i am looking for a free site. Bit strapped on cash now :|

Comment: tried that, cannot find a good one. There are some with some questions but a) those few questions don not seem to be very repesentative and b) they do not explain the answer.

I do appreciate your help though, let that be clear

Comment: Found this one: 
https://www.certlibrary.com/exam/AZ-900
Has no explanation/discussion  pertaining to the answers though